# How to find script error

Tags: wordpress, bots

My site has been down on and off for the last 10 hours. According to my host:

> It appears that the image
>   http://www.yetzira.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/ben10.jpg is being
>   hit hard by a ton of connections.

This has caused all sites on this server to be down for a long time. I don't know how to write scripts and don't recall ever using a script that could call this image. How can I find this script in my wordpress site?

My goal is to find this script and erase it but I have no idea how to do this.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a script problem, your image has been probably [hot-linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking) (used by another site).

- You should take a look at your server logs to find what is this site (using referer information).
- You can remove this file to avoid the server to be down again
- You can try to prevent hotlinking, try http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/